# Transparent proxy listening on sub-interfaces

Tags: networking, proxy, firewall, iptables, squid

I have iptables and squid on the same box. HTTP traffic doesn't seem to be going through the transparent proxy when I change my rules on the filter table.

What is the best point to filter http traffic when its being redirected through the proxy and forwarded on the Internet ?

**Topology:**

```
Internet < eth0 < eth1
                  eth1.10
```

**routing table**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.10.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1.10
```

**netstat:**

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.254:3128    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

**squid:**

```
http_port 192.168.10.254:3128 intercept
acl hq src 192.168.10.0/24
acl http port 80
http_access allow hq
http_access deny
```

**nat table:**

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth1.10 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.254:3128   
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

**filter table**

```
:INPUT ACCEPT 
:FORWARD ACCEPT 
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

This method works because the default policy is ACCEPT. Below are my filter rules which doesn't work with squid.

**filter table**

```
:INPUT DROP 
:FORWARD DROP 
:OUTPUT DROP 

-A INPUT -s 192.168.10.0/24 -i eth1.10 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT    
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT    
-A INPUT -i eth1.10 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT    
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT    
-A FORWARD -i eth1.10 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT    
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1.10 -j ACCEPT    
-A OUTPUT -o eth1.10 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT    
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT    
-A OUTPUT -o eth1.10 -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT    
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Let me know if you need more information, thanks.

Comment: I got it to work by creating a rule for the input and output hooks within netfilter. I was able to debug how traffic flows through each hook while the default policy was set to ACCEPT.

1) Flush all your rules and set the defualt policy to ACCEPT on the filter table

2) enable loggging through syslog with: sudo sysctl net.netfilter.nf_log.2=ipt_LOG
sudo modprobe ipt_LOG

Comment: 3) set some rules on the raw table, I used a generic rule to trace everything:

sudo iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -j TRACE
sudo iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -j TRACE

4) Now tail your logs as traffic traverses each hook within netfilter:

sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog